# beamerposter of size three A0

Tags: paper-size, beamerposter

I am quite new to beamerposter, but eager to take a chance to try it. There are conferences (e.g. CVPR) that requires poster to be 3 times an A0 size. I'm wondering if there's a natural way (supported way) to do it with beamerposter class? Or should I just go with A0 size and somehow zoom it up during printing?

Answer (score 2):

With the `size=custom` key you can select the paper size manually.

(the numbers below are just dummy values, you'll have to look up the correct values)

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[size=custom,width=77,height=107,scale=1.4]{beamerposter} 


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```